# Remove EOL in variable for comparing strings

Tags: robotframework

I use `Run Keyword Unless` comparing a variable and a string:

```
Run Keyword Unless  '${text}' == 'HelloWorld'      My Keyword     ${text}
```

Sometimes `${text}` consists of two lines separated by "\n" (eg. "One line\ntwo lines"). If so, the tests fails with an error:

```
Evaluating expression ''One line  
two lines' == 'HelloWorld'' failed: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (<string>, line 1)
```

I solved the problem removing '\n' with `String.Replace String` as follows:

```
${one_line_text}=     String.Replace String    ${text}     \n     ${SPACE}
Run Keyword Unless  '${one_line_text}' == 'HelloWorld'      My Keyword    ${text}
```

Is there a way to do it without explicit removing of EOL in a separate keyword?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about `${text.replace("\n", " ")}`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use python's string literals - `"""` or `'''` - and not change the string at all:

```
Run Keyword Unless  '''${text}''' == 'HelloWorld'      My Keyword     ${text}
```

They are designed for pretty much this purpose - to hold values having newline characters, plus quotes.